# ReactJs map undefined in IE10

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i saw similar questions and tried everything but not helped.

I'm getting error map is undefined in ie10 and ie11. 
After making this changes on my project, ie11 worked but ie10 not.

in my package.json:

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 10",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
```

i have install **core-js** package from npm and i put in my top level of my app, App.js:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import "core-js";
import 'core-js/es/set'
import 'core-js/es/map'
```

with these configuration my app works on ie11 but on ie10 not. What can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to install additional polyfills for `Array.map()` to work on [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

First, we install the polyfill library,

```
npm i react-app-polyfill
```

Then, we import the required polyfills in the `index.js`/`index.ts` of your app.

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9'
```

Comment: import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9'
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';  i made it like that right ie9 and ie11 import

Comment: Ahh.. I thought you only imported the one for ie11. So.. It still doesnt work?

Comment: Also, you need to import all of them on your index.js, not app.js

Comment: Okey i'm trying now

Comment: @user3348410 glad to help! Happy new year to you too :)

Comment: For me, I got an error, 'Map' is undefined. Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

`create-react-app` + IE10 = Hot-reload (`web-dev-serve` or whatever it's called) didn't work for me, something about dependency packages. I had to `npm run build` and then `serve -s build`. :)