# React undefined map in IE10

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

I am trying to adapt a React app to eork with IE. I saw similar questions and tried everything but not helped.

I'm getting "Map is undefined" error in IE9 and IE10. In IE11 everything is ok after doing this:

package.json:

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie >= 9"
    ]
  }
```

index.js:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import "core-js";
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/map';
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Duplicate [ReactJs map undefined in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540970/reactjs-map-undefined-in-ie10)

Comment: @GuyIncognito Map !== array::map

Comment: Without seeing the code it's unclear if this is Map or Array.map. The other question reports the exact same error message.

Comment: @GuyIncognito No disagreement over the ambiguity. OP here *has* the recommended `react-app-polyfill/ie9` package, however, so it *could* be big M `Map`.

Comment: Can you post related code which will throw the "Map is undefined" error?  Besides, you could post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: should just stop supporting IE, its dead