# How to make React app created by create-react-app support IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, create-react-app

I have a simple react app created by the latest version of create-react-app (that only support node version 14+). I am trying to make this app run in IE11. So as recommended, I did following:

- installed react-app-polyfill
- added two imports at the beginning of index.js: import "react-app-polyfill/ie11", import "react-app-polyfill/stable"
- added "ie 11" under the development in the package.json

I installed a chrome extension, IE Tab, and tested there. But still not working, I see following error when I open the chrome devtool:
IE: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'.  Source: http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63700

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue. You can add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#polyfill) for `endsWith()` so that it can work well in IE 11.

You can include the polyfill within `<script>` tag in **index.html**.

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you so much. I also need make the app work with IE10, I got following error, IE: Error: 'Map' is undefined. Can you help out too? Thanks.

Comment: IE 10 is too old. You can try if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540970/reactjs-map-undefined-in-ie10/59541013#59541013) can work.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution on the 3rd page of google. It's going to help you:

- The first thing you have to do - include polyfills from `react-app-polyfill` at the top of your app
- Then in package.json set up browserlist (add ie11, ie10, etc)
- In the end - add meta tag  in your public/index.html