# Pptxgenjs appears to not work in IE11 even with jszip@3.1.5

Tags: internet-explorer-11, pptxgenjs

Having read the previous versions of this question from 2020 this issue appears to have reared it's head again. I have tried these demos with my current jszip@3.7.0 and with jszip 3.1.5 using it as my application jszip and overwriting the jszip within pptxgenjs.

When using pptxgenjs in IE11 (Windows 10) it appears to work in that no errors are reported, what does happen is the browser alerts the user that: "You'll need a new app to open this blob link". The only option that is available at this point is then to go to "Look for an app in the Microsoft Store" of which no apps are available.

What this says to me is that pptxgenjs has done its job and has passed the blob link to the browser and the browser has said I have no clue you'll need to find something to open this.

I've attempted to run the demos in the same Windows 10/IE11 setup and they seem to do worse. the live demo doesn't error or offer the ability to download an app to support opening the blob link. The react demo errors to the console: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'. The Basic Demo in the complete library of demos fails like the live demo not returning an error or acknowledging anything.

Is this a known issue? Is there another step to help IE11 with the blob link? Can anyone else get the demos to work and I should be looking at something else? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Apologies if this wasn't clear, but the demos I was referring to were the pptxgenjs demos found here: https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/demos/ so focusing on the initial demo named 'Live Demo' the code that is being run is here: https://gist.github.com/gitbrent/84acbcaab54be0eba83f5206ef6ddd95#file-pptxgenjs_demo-js

Running this with all other key browsers such as edge, firefox and chrome all 'download' the generated file whereas running the same demo in IE11 fails silently.

Comment: Which demo do you use to test in IE11? Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. For the `endsWith` error, it seems that it doesn't use polyfill for IE11. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879134/how-to-make-react-app-created-by-create-react-app-support-ie11) for the solution.

Comment: @YuZhou I've updated my question, and focused on the pptxgenjs 'Live Demo' that is referenced here: https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/demos/ However, using IE11 running on Windows 10 I couldn't get any pptxgenjs demo to run. I wouldn't know how to set up a minimal code snippet for this issue as the issue arises from the use of IE11, not from code that does not work. The code appears to work on all other modern browsers.

Comment: I see. Even the official demo doesn't work in IE 11. It looks like PptxGenJS's issue. I suggest that you can [open an issue](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/issues) in PptxGenJS's GitHub to confirm if they have dropped the supported of IE 11.